# Reaching a variable from nested function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can somebody please explain me why the following code works?

```
function getLastName()
{
    fullName.lastName = "World";   
}

function writeName()
{
    fullName = {};
    fullName.firstName = "Hello";
    getLastName();
    document.write(fullName.firstName + " " + fullName.lastName);
}

writeName();
```

For some reason, `getLastName()` can reach local its enclosing method's local state. How can this work? And also should I utilize this feature of Javascript or it is considered as a bad practice? If it is a bad practice, could you please explain why?

You can see the actual code working here at http://jsbin.com/atituk/2/edit

Comment: I'd recommend to avoid this practice, as also most scenarios of global variables. Instead, define  local vars, pass them to submethods, ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have any local variables, that would require using the `var` keyword. All your variables are global and can be accessed anywhere within `window`, which is not considered good practice at all.

Answer (score 2):

You have not used the [`var` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) against `fullName` inside the `writeName` function, you are therefore taking it from the scope outside `writeName`. It continues up the chain until it reaches the outer most scope, at which point it creates a global.

Globals are, in general, bad practise as they are hard to keep track of and more likely to be overwritten by accident (e.g. in a race condition).

If you were using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) this would create an error instead of a global.

Comment: I liked the fact that you mentioned "use strict".

Comment: +1 for mentioning how to avoid this situation by using strict.

Answer (score 1):

You are using all variables of yours as global variables. So all are recognized everywhere. In order to have a better understanding of variable scopes in Javascript have a look at this great example https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/655316